# Passing variable name into {{ }} flask

Tags: html, mysql, flask, jinja2

I want to get image name from database and make it display at html file by this code

```
 <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/{{rows.infor_image}}') }}" style="width:50%; height:60%;">
```

but I dont know how to write in the correct syntax to get image to be display

I try to declare image_name in .py file but I dont know how to use it

```
@app.route('/herbsinfo/<id>')
def landing_page(id):


cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

#Query
cur.execute('SELECT version()')
result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM information where infor_id = %s",[id])

rows = cur.fetchone()
image_name = rows['infor_image']
if result > 0:
    return render_template('herbsinfo.html', rows=rows,image_name=image_name)
```

or I can display image in other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/'+image_name) }}" style="width:50%; height:60%;">
```

or

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/'+rows.infor_image) }}" style="width:50%; height:60%;">
```

You don't need to add extra `{{ }}`